# combining ggfortify autoplot with changepoint package functions (cpt.meanvar)

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecast

I am using autoplot function in ggfortify package to plot time series plot with forecast and fit, here is how I am doing it

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
fc <- forecast(fdeaths)
autoplot(fc)
autoplot(fc) + geom_line(aes(y = fitted(fc)), col = "red")
```

Now I want to show the time period which has a shift in the mean as well show mean before and after shift, all on the plot above

I am able to do it separately using 'changepoint' package, syntax is as below

```
library(changepoint)
autoplot(cpt.mean(fdeaths))

plot(cpt.mean(fdeaths),cpt.col='blue')
```

combined view of all of these would give very powerful insight, requesting help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17kI9.gif)

Comment: I could not clearly understand your doubt. Could you provide a sample image? Anything use the imgur site to host the image.

Comment: @ bbiasi ... please find the image, want I am looking for is the chart on the right  which is the combination of all 3 charts on the left

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example. But, it has to automate with looping the plot of segments (`geom_segment`) and vline (`geom_vline`).

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
library(changepoint)
library(lubridate)

fc <- forecast(fdeaths)
cp <- changepoint::cpt.mean(fdeaths)
plot(cp,cpt.col='blue')
# plot(x = 1:length(c(fdeaths)), y = c(fdeaths), type = "l")
Vikram <- data.frame(ts = c(fdeaths),
                     Obs = seq(lubridate::ymd('1974-01-01'),
                               lubridate::ymd('1979-12-01'), by = "1 month"),
                     fitted = fitted(fc))
Vikram_md <- changepoint::param.est(cp)[[1]] # mean
# cp@cpts  # change-points
cp_ <- cp@cpts

autoplot(fc) + geom_line(aes(y = fitted(fc)), col = "red") +
  geom_segment(x = Vikram$Obs[1], 
               y = Vikram_md[1], yend = Vikram_md[1],
               xend = Vikram$Obs[1] %m+% months(cp_[1]), 
               size = 1.2, col = "blue") +
  geom_segment(x = Vikram$Obs[1] %m+% months(cp_[1]), 
               y = Vikram_md[2], yend = Vikram_md[2],
               xend = Vikram$Obs[1] %m+% months(cp_[2]), 
               size = 1.2, col = "blue") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Vikram$Obs[1] %m+% months(cp_[2])),
             linetype = "dashed", colour = "red")
```

[image]